# Several questions with QtCreator

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

I'm working on a project which should have GUI written in Qt. I'm thinking using QtCreator as a development IDE, but there are some problems I'm facing. The project should have a dll file which shouldn't be dependent on any qt library/module, it should use only winapi and it should be compiled with both x86 and x64. So my questions are:

- Is it possible to use QtCreator to compile a dll which doesn't have any dependency on qt modules. If yes, how?
- Is it possible to use MinGW x86 & x64 to compile a single project? If so, how can I specify which compiler to use?

This is my first project with Qt, and I'm not a C++ guru, so please describe the details as good as you can :-)
Your help is much appreciated.

**UPDATE**

---

Allright, I tried compiling the project as Berk suggested, but I have still a problem. The output has a dependency on LIBGCC_S_DW2-1.DLL and MSVCRT.DLL. Is it possible to remove a dependency on LIBGCC_S_DW2-1.DLL and link MSVCRT.DLL inside my exe/dll (just like MS VC does).

Comment: `LIBGCC_S_DW2-1.DLL` dependency comes from mingw. You need to use Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler. Please check my updated my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Qt Creator as pure C++ IDE. It supports generic project (qtcreator project), cmake and qmake.

- Using generic project, you have to define all of your make scripts. I don't recommend this.
- Using cmake you can do many things as i heard but i don't have any experience on that.
- Using qmake your project depends on qmake tool. But your application does not have to depend any qt library. To accomplish this you need to add `CONFIG -= qt` flag to your qmake project file.

I recommend qmake approach. You will get best experience with qmake based project on Qt Creator.

You can do it via Qt Creator's interface. You need to define both compilers first.

**EDIT:**

As i can see these dependencies your qmake is compiled by mingw. These're mingw's dependencies. So you cannot avoid from `LIBGCC_S_DW2-1.DLL` using mingw. All Qt dependent dll's named like Qt*.dll. So your library is not linked with any Qt library.

You need to use Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler.

For qmake based projects, Qt Creator determines compiler, linker information from detected Qt directory. If your Qt version is compiled with mingw, it uses mingw for your project too. If you need to compile with another compiler you have 2 choices:

- Compile Qt with another preferred compiler. (It may take some hours!)
- Make new build configuration with your preferred compiler's information.

First one is essential for Qt based projects. If you have to compile Qt based parts too. I think you should compile Qt with MSVC Compiler (`-mkspec win32-msvc20xx`). Then you can add new compiler directory to Qt Versions (Options->Qt) and use it. It's easy.

But if you don't use any Qt parts. Compiling qt is not a good choice. Create a new build configuration for your project in Qt Creator and set/override some variables. (You need to override qmake's spec command switch to win32-msvc20xx, then you need to add MSVC Compiler path to environment variables. Also you need to override make command for all build steps to nmake or jom)

As you said that your project's GUI is written with Qt. First approach will be better for you.

Comment: Thanks Berk, I'll check it out this evening. BTW, does qmake modifies/alters compiled output?

Comment: No it's only a wrapper. It generates makefiles (for mingw/gcc) or visual studio project files (for visual c++ compiler) then executes build action. By using qmake your project files will be more compiler independent.

Comment: Thanks, +1 to your answer :). Now it's more clear. I'll check your solution soon and if everything goes well mark your answer as answer :-). Thanks again

Comment: Thanks for your help Berk. I want to use MinGW for both, x86 and x64 development without any Qt library. I don't think I need to recompile qt, new build config should suffice. But I can't seem to make it work. I added a new build configuration, I created a new tool chain for x64 MinGW but I cant set my project to use the new tool chain. It always points to the default one: "Mingw as a GCC for Windows targets". Is there any solution to set the new tool chain for my project. Thanks again Berk.

Comment: Sadly i cannot find any simple way to select new toolchain. Qt Creator always uses installed Qt version's toolchain. But you can override mkspec in Qt Creator's project settings.